# Nesting foreach loops

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop, foreach

I've been trying to figure this out for several days now and I've decided to throw in the towel and ask for help :)

I'm building a project management tool. I have a edit-page where admins can edit the project members and their role at the project.

I want my code to output the elements like this:

[image: Desired output]

My current output:

[image: Current output]

I want the code to ouput `<div class="row"></div>` around the two `<div class="col-sm-3"></div>`. Something is wrong with my nesting of the foreach-loops.

My PHP-code

```
foreach($results2 as $resulto) { // start outer foreach

    echo "<div class='col-sm-3' id='medarbejder'>"; // start medarbejder
    echo "<select class='selectpicker form-control' name='medarbejder[]'>";     
    echo "<option value='$resulto[medarbejderId]' name='medarbejder'";

    echo "selected>";
    echo $resulto['medarbejderNavn'];
    echo "</option>";

    foreach($results as $result) { // start inner foreach           

        echo "<option value='$result[medarbejderId]' name='medarbejder'";
        echo ">";
        echo $result['medarbejderNavn'];
        echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "</div>"; // end inner medarbejdernavn
}

echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

foreach($resultsrolle as $resulto) { // start outer foreach
    echo "<div class='col-sm-3' id='medarbejder'>"; // start medarbejder
    echo "<select class='selectpicker form-control' name='medarbejder[]'>";     
    echo "<option value='$resulto[rolleId]' name='medarbejder'";
    echo "selected>";
    echo $resulto['rolle'];
    echo "</option>";

    foreach($ArrayProjektRoller as $result) { // start inner foreach            
        echo "<option value='$result[id]' name='medarbejder'";
        echo ">";

        echo $result['type'];
        echo "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";   
    echo "</div>"; // end rolle 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: so this has nothing to do with php. more of a css thing, right?

Comment: It's not about CSS.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to put a space in between `echo "<option value='$resulto[medarbejderId]' name='medarbejder'";` and `echo "selected>";`

so you need a space between the two `echo " selected>";`

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, although putting this as a comment would have been good as its an obvious error

Comment: Noted and yes that's a typo.